# sliding onClick doesn't translate first time

Tags: onclick, slider, counter, translation, sliding

**Can you help me for this code... I want to translate sliders but on first click (for exemple if I click on sliding to right = -600px) it doesn't slide...**

```
const [slidingAvis, setSlidingAvis] = useState(0)
  function handleSliderAvis(direction) {
    if (direction == 'left') {
      setSlidingAvis(slidingAvis - 600)
      document.querySelector('.avis .sliders-avis').style.transform = 'translateX(-' + slidingAvis + 'px)';
    } else {
      setSlidingAvis(slidingAvis + 600)
      document.querySelector('.avis .sliders-avis').style.transform = 'translateX(-' + slidingAvis + 'px)';
    }
}
```

**on first click, it doesn't translate to -600px.. however I increase the slide before translation**

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I put the translation of slider in useEffect

```
const [slidingAvis, setSlidingAvis] = useState(0)
  const [d, setD] = useState()
  function HandleSliderAvis(direction) {
    if (direction == 'left') {
      setD('left')
      setSlidingAvis(slidingAvis - 600)
    } else {
      setD('right')
      setSlidingAvis(slidingAvis + 600)
    }

  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (d == 'left') {
      document.querySelector('.avis .sliders-avis').style.transform = 'translateX(-' + slidingAvis + 'px)';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.avis .sliders-avis').style.transform = 'translateX(-' + slidingAvis + 'px)';
    }
    console.log(slidingAvis)
  }, [slidingAvis])
```